# Is this proof of uncountability of Cantor set true?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

To construct Cantor set $C$, start with $I_1=[0,1]$ and define $$E_1=\{0,1\}=\{x:x\text{ is an  end point of the set }I_1\}.$$ $\operatorname{card}(E)=\#(E)=2$. After deleting the middle open interval $\big(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\big)$ we get $I_2=\big[0,\frac{1}{3}\big]\cup\big[\frac{2}{3},1\big]$ and $$E_2=\big\{0,\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3},1\big\}=\{x:x\text{ is an end point of the intervals, consisting remainder set }I_2\}$$ so $\#(E_2)=4=2^2$. Continue in this fashion. The set $I_n$ consists of $2^{n-1}$ intervals so $\#(E_n)=2^n$. Note that if $x$ is an end point of one the intervals in $I_k$ for some $k$ then $x\in C$. Thus $E_k\subset C$ for all $k$ and this implies $E=\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\subseteq C$. (I am not sure if $E=C$. The first question is whether or not the two sets are same.)  $\#(E_k)=2^k\leq \#(E)$ for all $k$ so can we deduce that $2^{\aleph_0}\leq\#(E)$?

I searched the proofs for the uncountability of the Cantor set but most of them uses ternary expansion. If this proof is true and if there is a reference for this proof, please give the reference. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I’m afraid that this argument doesn’t work. It’s true that $\#(E_n)=2^n$ for each $n$, and it’s true that $E\subseteq C$. However, $E$ is the union of countably many finite sets, so $E$ is only countable: all you’ve shown is that $C$ is infinite. And no, $E$ is not all of $C$. As a matter of fact, $E$ consists of those numbers in $[0,1]$ having terminating ternary (base three) expansions using only the digits $0$ and $2$, while $C$ consists of those numbers in $[0,1]$ having arbitrary ternary expansions using only $0$ and $2$. For example,

$${0.02020202\ldots}_{\text{three}}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac2{3^{2n}}=\frac{2/9}{1-1/9}=\frac14\in C\setminus E\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, the number of disjoint intervals, hence also their endpoints, is countable.